# Cauchy problem with parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution $u_{\lambda}(t)$ of the following Cauchy problem:
\begin{cases} 
u'(t) = 1 + \lambda \sin u(t) \\
u(0) = 0
\end{cases}
as the changes of $\lambda \in ]0, 1[$
and evaluate (for each fixed $t$) the value of the limits: 
$$v_0(t) = \lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0^+} u_\lambda(t) $$
$$v_1(t) = \lim_{\lambda \rightarrow  1^-} u_\lambda(t) $$

and verify that $v_0(t) = u_0 (t)$ and $v_1(t) = u_1(t)$ for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to analytically solve the ODE :

[image]

[image]